# Object cannot be sent between threads safely

Tags: rust

I'm trying to start a thread by passing the an object to a method.

```
let coordinator_handle = start_thread(&mut coordinator); // impl EventDriven

pub fn start_thread(event_handler: &mut dyn EventDriven) -> JoinHandle<()> {
    event_handler.initialize();
    return std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut last_time = std::time::Instant::now();
        loop {
            event_handler.on_timer(std::time::Instant::now().duration_since(last_time).as_micros());
            last_time = std::time::Instant::now();
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

But I'm getting the following error with this.

> ```
> | 17  |     return std::thread::spawn(move || {
> |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `dyn EventDriven` cannot be sent between threads safely
> ```

What am doing wrong here? And how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with the following changes

```
pub fn start_thread(event_handler: impl EventDriven + 'static) -> JoinHandle<()> {
```

and

```
let coordinator_handle = start_thread(coordinator);
```